# How to run CLI app on docker for localstack?

Tags: python, docker, localstack

I am working on a CLI App in python for AWS SQS(which is run on localstack) on docker. Here's my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.8"
networks:
  localstack-net:
    name: localstack-net
    driver: bridge
 
services:
  localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack
    privileged: true
    networks:
      - localstack-net
    ports:
      - "4576:4576"
    environment:
      - DEBUG=1
      - EDGE_PORT=4576
      - DATA_DIR=/tmp/localstack/data
      - SERVICES=sqs:4567
    volumes:
      - ./.temp/localstack:/tmp/localstack
      - ./localstack_setup:/docker-entrypoint-initaws.d/
  
  cli_app:
    build: 
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: my_app
```

and here's my dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim
RUN useradd --create-home --shell /bin/bash app_user
WORKDIR /home/app_user
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
USER app_user
COPY . .
CMD ["bash"]
```

The problem that occurs is that the service `cli_app` exits when I run the command `docker-compose up`.

What can I do to rectify this problem?

Comment: Your CMD is just bash, so you're never running your python code, but also, if your code doesn't remain running and just send data to the SQS queue, then this is expected behaviour - the script will exit, and the container stops

Comment: @OneCricketeer Can you guide me on what to do? I want to keep my container running

Comment: 1) You need to change `CMD` to run `["your_app,py"]` 2) Why do you need to keep it running if the app just starts, sends some data to SQS, then stops? What else do you need it to do?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I want to fetch the data through the app and show it